# Duplicate same filename adding date as a form of dated backup

Tags: bash, duplicates, backup, filenames

In Linuxmint, you can copy a filename and append the date with the following command in the terminal:

```
cp test.txt file_`date +"%Y%m%d"`.txt
```

This duplicates the file with the following name: "file_20221024.txt", which can be saved as a form of backup of the file. I would like to put this short command as an option when I right-click a file in my system: (Linuxmint Mate with Caja for folder structure).

I know it must be possible by invoking a saved file in my system with a routine that should assign the selected file to a function, but I don't know how to write it and implement it. Any help or guideline is welcome.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you would make right-clicking a file in the Caja file manager to invoke a certain program (script in your case). This is a question on how to use Caja (and how it passes the filename to your script) and should be asked at [su].

Answer (score 1):

I use this bash function:

```bash
backup() {
    local file new n=0
    local fmt='%s.%(%Y%m%d)T_%02d'
    for file; do
        while :; do
            # shellcheck disable=SC2059
            printf -v new "$fmt" "$file" -1 $((++n))
            [[ -e $new ]] || break
        done
        command cp -vp "$file" "$new"
    done
}
```

I can't help you to integrate that into your desktop environment

Comment: @glenn_jackman, I've  rewriten your nested loops, with `for file; do while printf -v new "$fmt" "$file" -1 $((++n)); do [[ -e $new ]] || break done; done` 
It seems to produce the same results, what are the odds of it breaking at some point? :-)

Comment: check the manual: when does `printf` return a non-success exit status.